# Спящий парикмахер

Tags: c++, mpi

Помогите разобраться как реализовать задачу "Спящий парикмахер", используя обмен сообщениями: Send и Recv.
Разобрался, как реализовать через Семафоры и Мониторы, но с сообщениями не понимаю :(

Проблема спящего парикмахера - классическая задача паралельного программирования.
Проблема заключается в обеспечении того, чтобы парикмахер работал, когда есть клиенты, и отдыхал, когда клиентов нет.
У нас есть 1 парикмахер (Процесс 0) и остальные клиенты. Аналогия основана на гипотетической парикмахерской с одним парикмахером. У парикмахера есть одно рабочее место и приемная с несколькими стульями. Когда парикмахер заканчивает подстригать клиента, он отпускает клиента и затем идет в приёмную, чтобы посмотреть, есть ли там ожидающие клиенты. Если они есть, он приглашает одного из них и стрижет его. Если ждущих клиентов нет, он возвращается к своему креслу и спит в нем.

Main:

```
int size, rank;
std::queue<int> visitors;

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0) {
    std::cout << "I am a barber [" << rank << "]" << std::endl;
    Barber(visitors);
}
    
if (rank != 0) {
    std::cout << "I'm not a barber [" << rank << "]" << std::endl;
    Client(visitors, chairs, rank);
}
```

Barber:

```
MPI_Status st;
MPI_Request request;
int num;

while (1) {
    if (visitors.size() == 0)
        continue;
    MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, visitors.front(), MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
    visitors.pop();
    std::cout << "I'm cutting process " << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "There are " << visitors.size() << " people left in the queue" << std::endl;
}
```

Client:

```
void Client(std::queue<int>& visitors, int chairs, int rank) {
if (visitors.size() < chairs) {
    visitors.push(rank);
    MPI_Send(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
}
```

Comment: возможно стоит добавить описание задачи "Спящий парикмахер", т.к. может быть не понятно о чем речь

Comment: в mpi память процессов абсолютно независима, так что `visitors.push` в клиенте делать бессмысленно — парикмахер должен самостоятельно контролировать свою очередь...

Comment: Но если очередь заполняет сам парикмахер, как тогда процессы будут знать, кто должен следующий "зайти"?